# What do the hyphens represent in "mdb_reader_list"?

Tags: python, lmdb

I am using the [py-lmdb python binding for LMDB](https://github.com/jnwatson/py-lmdb/). I am confused what the meaning of the hyphens is in the "reader lock table" returned by the function [`mdb_reader_list`](http://www.lmdb.tech/doc/group__mdb.html#ga8550000cd0501a44f57ee6dff0188744) for LMDB (or `env.readers` for the py-lmdb binding).

My best guess is the hyphens represent a committed transaction. In my program, I am pretty certain that whenever I open a reader, I will commit it before opening a second one. In particular, whenever I create a new reader, either the reader lock table is empty, or every row (besides the header) of the reader lock table contains a hyphen. However, the reader lock table will fill up with these hyphen rows, eventually raising a `MDB_READERS_FULL` error (`lmdb.ReadersFullError` for the py-lmdb binding). I genuinely have no idea why this happens.